# How to do Auto complete in SharePoint 2013 search configuration?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, search-results, enterprise-search

I am not getting proper result when I write `doc` but when I write `doc*` it shows proper results. I need all results even I write `doc` or `doc*` or `document`?

Anyone have idea regarding this or any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

You can use query rules, add condition then action

Comment: can you please elaborate query rules?

Comment: In a query rule, you specify conditions and correlated actions. When a query meets the conditions in a query rule, the search system performs the actions specified in the rule to improve the relevance of the search results, such as by narrowing results or changing the order in which results are displayed. For example, a query rule condition could be that a term in a query matches a particular term in a SharePoint term set, or that a query is frequently performed on a particular result source in a search system, such as videos.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/jj871676.aspx

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to build a search suggestion auto complete list, you can store the suggestion text in a txt file for the specific character like "doc", check the steps in this blog:
[Enable Query Suggestions in SharePoint 2013 Search](http://www.jeanpaulva.com/index.php/2014/04/03/enable-query-suggestions-in-sharepoint-2013-search/)